# Getting Installed softwares from remote host using wmi

Tags: c#, wmi

I want to retrieve Softwares installed from remote host. I want to get details from the registry and not from Win32_Product.I am using wmi. I have tried so many examples from the net. Most of them are in vb.net i need in C#. can any one post the code..

This is the code i am using

```
string regKeyToGet=@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\";
string keyToRead= "DisplayName"; 
ConnectionOptions oConn = new ConnectionOptions(); 
oConn.Username = "Ravinilson"; 
oConn.Password = "ravi"; 

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"//" + RemotePC + @"/root/default",      oConn); 
ManagementClass registry = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null); 
// Returns a specific value for a specified key 
ManagementBaseObject inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue"); 
nParams["sSubKeyName"] = regKeyToGet; 
inParams["sValueName"] = keyToRead; 
ManagementBaseObject outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null); 
return outParams["sValue"].ToString();
```

but it is giving "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.
I am getting installed applications from "Win32_Product".But it is returning only windows products.That's why i want to get data from the registry "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\".

Comment: You've been here for seven months, asked nine questions, never accepted an answer, never submitted a vote, and here you're basically asking us to give you code without any effort on your part. I'm afraid that won't end well...

Comment: oh sorry..if i got the answer from u i just used it.i don't know i should accept it.

Comment: Why in the world would you not want to use the documented way of doing this? Don't go hunting through the Registry for things. And it is exceedingly trivial to convert VB.NET code into C# code. You need to learn to expend a little effort for yourself before posting questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the below script.

```
#PRAGMA AUTORECOVER
[dynamic, provider("RegProv"),
ProviderClsid("{fe9af5c0-d3b6-11ce-a5b6-00aa00680c3f}"),   
ClassContext("local|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows
\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall")] 
class InstalledSoftware 
{
   [key] string KeyName;
   [read, propertycontext("DisplayName")]      string DisplayName;
   [read, propertycontext("DisplayVersion")]   string  DisplayVersion;
   [read, propertycontext("InstallDate")]      string InstallDate;
   [read, propertycontext("Publisher")]        string Publisher;
};
```

Save above script as ".mof" file. After that you need to compile this script by using the commandprompt command "mofcomp filename.mof" . for this u need to have admin privileges. after compiling the file the above class "InstalledSoftware" will get added to the wmi classes in default root.

now u will be able to access installed applications in that pc using the class name "InstalledSoftware" through wmi. One tricky thing is that we need to compile the above script in all the remote machines from which u need to access installed softwares.